# VcXsrv: Dedicated mouse/keyboard to different display instances, multiseating

Tags: linux, windows-10, multiseat, vcxsrv

What Im looking for is a way to run multiple instances of VcXsrv on windows 10, and have each instance set with a dedicated mouse and keyboard (One thing I find with windows VcXsrv is that the mouse does not allow for its position to be set, or 'lock' onto the window with 3D game like applications such as Minecraft), allowing for multiple users to use one computer at once.

This may not be possible with this software, so if not, I ask free alternatives that follow a similar setup of multiple X servers on one computer for multi-seating.

I am not the best in this field, so all advice is appreciated.  Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

I now only one multiseat for Windows 10 - [Aster](https://www.ibik.ru). It has 30-days trial - try it

Comment: This if not the software I am looking for due to its price